# How can I have perfectly centered navigation bar with equally wide links?

Tags: html, css

So I want to have a centered navigation menu/bar on my website, kind of like the one on [Ovh's website](https://www.ovh.com/fr/). What CSS do I put (don't include colors). Here is my HTML:

```
<div class = "nav">
        <div class = "top_page">
            <h1 class = "mainTitle">Exatreo</h1>
            <p class = "slogan">Slogan</p>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class = "container">
            <ul class="center-links">
                <a href="" class = "content" >Home</a></li>
                <a href="/about" class = "content" >About</a>
                <a href="/projects" class = "content" >Projects</a>
                <a href="/recruit" class = "content" >recruting</a>
                <a href="/help" class = "content" >Help</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What problems are you having? Can you post an image of what you get using your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid, `ul` can only have `li` as direct children...but we can use a `nav` element instead.

**Method 1: Table Layout**

```css
.center-links {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-links a {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="center-links">
    <a href="" class="content">Home</a>
    <a href="/about" class="content">About</a>
    <a href="/projects" class="content">Projects</a>
    <a href="/recruit" class="content">recruting</a>
    <a href="/help" class="content">Help</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Method 2: Flexbox**

```css
.center-links {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-links a {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="center-links">
    <a href="" class="content">Home</a>
    <a href="/about" class="content">About</a>
    <a href="/projects" class="content">Projects</a>
    <a href="/recruit" class="content">recruting</a>
    <a href="/help" class="content">Help</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```