# Horizontal Menu items span width of container

Tags: css, list, menu

I've searched for this question and cant find it anywhere here.

There is a horizontal list of 9 menu items, and the container has a width of 1200px.

Currently there is a right margin on each menu item (apart from the last) to space them out, but the menu items need to span from the left to right edge regardless of screen/browser width. Even though media queries are used to reduce the right margin as the browser is minimized, it still does the following:

- leaves a small gap on the right of the list.
- pushes the last menu item to the next line.

Is this a JQuery solution?

```
.menu           {width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}
.menu li        {display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 0 36.7px; position: relative;}
.menu li:nth-of-type(1) {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: Try `display:flex`. Please post your HTML or create a jsfiddle

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244925/how-can-i-have-perfectly-centered-navigation-bar-with-equally-wide-links

Comment: Not really related as I don't want anything centered, I want the left edge of the very first word to be at the left edge of the container, and the right edge of the very last word to be at the right edge of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `display:flex`. Below is an example

```css
.menu {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: palegreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I added flex to the ul, flew-grow: 1 to all li's and flex-grow: 0 to the li:last-child so the list is edge to edge, works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You could use percentage widths with percentage margins. Lets say we want a `0.5%` right margin per item. There's 8 items that require a margin; so 8 x 0.5 equals 4%. So that 4% is reserved for margin but after that we still have 96% to play with. So divide 96% by 9 items with makes `10.66%` per item.

```css
.menu {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  width: 10.66%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li.last {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li class="last">9</li>
</ul>
```

The advantage of this over CSS3 `flex` is that it will work on pretty much any browser although you might have to tweak (round down) the widths in IE7 because of subpixel rendering issues if you support it).